# XAML ComboBox default SelectedIndex is not shown

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a ComboBox with some values, and I want to have two things working at once.

Here is my ComboBox and I want to show the 10 as default value and also to bind it to a double? Distance property.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
          SelectedIndex="1"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Distance, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">10</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>100</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1000</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And here is the converter:

```
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = value as ComboBoxItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(item.Content.ToString(), out d))
                return d;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in this code, The selected item 10 is not show at the start of the application.
If I will remove the line with the converter, then it will show the selected item 10, but then, I can't bind it to the double? Distance property. I dont want to write a code behind for it, such as: Convert.ToDouble(combobox1.SelectedValue)...

What can I do to make both things work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate combo box items from ViewModel. Moreover you should not use `SelectedValue` property, instead of it you should use `SelectedItem`. See the below given code.

XAML

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" ItemsSource="{Binding DistanceCollection}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Distance, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public class viewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public viewModel()
    {
        DistanceCollection = new ObservableCollection<string> 
        {
            "1",
            "10",
            "100",
            "1000"
        };

        Distance = double.Parse(DistanceCollection[1].ToString());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> DistanceCollection { get; set; }

    private double _Distance;
    public double Distance
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _Distance; 
        }
        set
        {
            _Distance = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Distance");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Converter

```
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string item = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(item, out d))
                return d;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```